# Transpose adds another row/column to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

When trying to transpose the following table:

| Sample | input_test | input_test2 | input_test3 | ip_test | ip_test2 | ip_test3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tRNA | 5 | 5 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| CDS | 9330 | 9330 | 9330 | 26680 | 26680 | 26680 |
| 3utr | 2525 | 2525 | 2525 | 3810 | 3810 | 3810 |
| 5utr | 1966 | 1966 | 1966 | 5006 | 5006 | 5006 |
| 5ss | 960 | 960 | 960 | 1972 | 1972 | 1972 |
| 3ss | 932 | 932 | 932 | 1989 | 1989 | 1989 |
| proxintron | 1221 | 1221 | 1221 | 1228 | 1228 | 1228 |
| distintron | 6450 | 6450 | 6450 | 4744 | 4744 | 4744 |
| noncoding_exon | 1477 | 1477 | 1477 | 1302 | 1302 | 1302 |
| noncoding_5ss | 25 | 25 | 25 | 35 | 35 | 35 |
| noncoding_3ss | 16 | 16 | 16 | 29 | 29 | 29 |
| noncoding_proxintron | 68 | 68 | 68 | 80 | 80 | 80 |
| noncoding_distintron | 629 | 629 | 629 | 441 | 441 | 441 |
| allexonic | 15298 | 15298 | 15298 | 36798 | 36798 | 36798 |
| allintronic | 10301 | 10301 | 10301 | 10518 | 10518 | 10518 |
| all | 27131 | 27131 | 27131 | 49060 | 49060 | 49060 |

I get this:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sample | tRNA | CDS | 3utr | 5utr | 5ss | 3ss | proxintron | distintron | noncoding_exon | noncoding_5ss | noncoding_3ss | noncoding_proxintron | noncoding_distintron | allexonic | allintronic | all |
| input_test | 5 | 9330 | 2525 | 1966 | 960 | 932 | 1221 | 6450 | 1477 | 25 | 16 | 68 | 629 | 15298 | 10301 | 27131 |
| input_test2 | 5 | 9330 | 2525 | 1966 | 960 | 932 | 1221 | 6450 | 1477 | 25 | 16 | 68 | 629 | 15298 | 10301 | 27131 |
| input_test3 | 5 | 9330 | 2525 | 1966 | 960 | 932 | 1221 | 6450 | 1477 | 25 | 16 | 68 | 629 | 15298 | 10301 | 27131 |
| ip_test | 1 | 26680 | 3810 | 5006 | 1972 | 1989 | 1228 | 4744 | 1302 | 35 | 29 | 80 | 441 | 36798 | 10518 | 49060 |
| ip_test2 | 1 | 26680 | 3810 | 5006 | 1972 | 1989 | 1228 | 4744 | 1302 | 35 | 29 | 80 | 441 | 36798 | 10518 | 49060 |
| ip_test3 | 1 | 26680 | 3810 | 5006 | 1972 | 1989 | 1228 | 4744 | 1302 | 35 | 29 | 80 | 441 | 36798 | 10518 | 49060 |

Why is there an additional row with numbers on top? This is driving me nuts, I've tried so many options with `index=False`, `df_merged.set_index('Sample',inplace=True)`, etc.

This is the code:

```
# transpose

    df_merged = pd.read_csv(str(save_path) + "all_stats_matrix.csv")

    df_merged = df_merged.T

    df_merged.to_csv(str(save_path) + "all_stats_matrix.csv")
```

Comment: have you used `df_merged.transpose()` after `df_merged.set_index('Sample',inplace=True)`, whats the output? (Also, cant see where you used df_merged.set_index('Sample',inplace=True))

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively if your goal is to have the first row as headers instead of the numbers. Use this:

```
df_merged = pd.read_csv(str(save_path) + "all_stats_matrix.csv")

df_merged = df_merged.T

df_merged = df_merged.rename(columns=df_merged.iloc[0]).drop(df_merged.index[0])

df_merged.to_csv(str(save_path) + "all_stats_matrix.csv")
```

It is not the most clean way, but should get the job done.

Answer (score -1):

How about: `df_merged.set_index('Sample').transpose()`?